# Wp Query caching

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i have a little problem here.. let me introduce...

i have a script to create a shortcode.. here's the script..

```
//shortcode stock
function stok($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "id" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'  
    ), $atts));  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS value_sum FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents WHERE prodid = '".$id."'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    $stock = '<center><br><b>STOK TERJUAL :</b><div class="nscountdown"><table><thead><tr><td>'.$row['value_sum'].'</td></tr></thead></table></div></center>';
    return $stock;
}  
add_shortcode("stok", "stok");
```

as you can see there is a query to sum a column

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS value_sum FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents WHERE prodid = '".$id."'");
```

Nah.. the problem is.. how to cache the result, because that query make my server load average become spiked...

any solution??

thanks before....

Comment: Doesn't look like this query should cause any issues. How many carts can have one product?. I suggest running 'explain' on that query and make sure MySQL is correctly tuned. – martincho just now edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) is what you need.

```
function stok($atts, $content = null) {  
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
        "id" => 'http://net.tutsplus.com'  
    ), $atts));  

    if ( false === ( $query_cache = get_transient( md5($id) ) ) ) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) AS value_sum FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents WHERE prodid = '".$id."'"); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $stock = '<center><br><b>STOK TERJUAL :</b><div class="nscountdown"><table><thead><tr><td>'.$row['value_sum'].'</td></tr></thead></table></div></center>';

        // set one hour lifetime cache with the name of md5($id)
        set_transient( md5($id), $stock, 60*60*1 );     
        return $stock;
    }
    return $query_cache;
}  
add_shortcode("stok", "stok");
```

Comment: Double check if your query is working. I tested it with a simple string with `date()` embedded with a short lifetime such as 30 seconds and it's working.

Comment: btw how if i want to set the expiration to 1 days

Comment: It's easy. Just change `60*60*1` to `60*60*24`. It means 24 hours.